# directional derivative of a function with discontinuity$f(x,y)= \frac{x^{5}}{\sqrt{9 x^{8}+9(y + 2)^{8}}}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, vectors, partial-derivative, differential

Okay so this was a long problem which I solved completely. I did all the questions and I'm just looking for someone to check my solutions. (For part $(2)$ I used the method of setting $f(x,-2)$ for the partial derivative with respect to $x$, then setting $f(0,y)$ for partial derivative with respect to $y$. Idk if it's right though)
All help is much appreciated, thanks!

[screenshot of work from website, transcribed below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3CeW.png)

> Define  $f:R^2→R$  by
>
> $f(x,y):= \begin{cases} \frac{x^{5}}{\sqrt{9 x^{8}+9(y + 2)^{8}}}, &
> > \text{if } (x,y) \neq (0,-2), \\ 0, & \text{if } (x,y) = (0,-2).
> > \end{cases} $.
>
> $(1)$ Calculate the partial derivatives of  $f$  with respect to  $x$  and to  $y$  assuming  $(x,y)≠(0,−2)$.

$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x,y)= (x^4(x^8+5(y+2)^8))/(3(x^8+(y+2)^8)^{3/2})$

$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x,y)=\left(-4\left(x^5\right)\left(y+2\right)^7\right)/\left(3\left(x^8+\left(y+2\right)^8\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)$

> $(2)$  Calculate  $∂f/∂x(0,−2)$,  and  $∂f/∂y(0,−2)$

$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (0,-2)= 1/3$

$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (0,-2)= 0$

> $(3)$ Calculate the directional derivative of  $f$  at  $(0,−2)$  along a general vector $ v⃗ =(a,b)$

$D_{\vec{v}}(f)(x,y)=1/3a$

> $(4)$ Calculate  $∇f(0,−2)⋅(a,b) .$

$=1/3a$

> $(5)$ By comparing part $(3)$ and $(4)$, what can you conclude?
>
> $a)$   $f$ is $C^1$ and differentiable.
>
> $b)$  $f$ is $C^1$ but not differentiable.
>
> $c)$  $f$ is not $C^1$ but is differentiable.
>
> $d)$  $f$ is not $C^1$ and is not differentiable.

I chose $c)$.

Comment: What is your definition of $C^1$?

Comment: @MarkS. $C^1$ is class of differentiable functions whose partial derivatives are continuous.

Comment: If $C^1$ has "differentiable" in its definition, it would seem like b) is the one choice 5) couldn't possibly be. Is there something I'm missing/can you provide your reasoning for 5)?

Comment: @MarkS. whoops i meant $c$

Comment: @MarkS. did the other parts look right though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your title is wrong: the function is continuous, despite being piecewise-defined.
2. Parts (1), (2), (4), are correct, and so is the method for (2). (4) is correct because one takes as a *definition* $\nabla f(0,-2) := (\frac{df}{dx}(0,-2), \ \frac{df}{dy}(0,-2))$.
3. Part (3) is wrong. You cannot use $D_vf(x) = \nabla f(x)\cdot v$ without checking differentiability. Instead, directly compute
   $$ D_{(a,b)}f(0,-2) := \lim_{t\downarrow 0} \frac{f(0+ta,-2+tb) - f(0,-2)}t.$$
   You should see the square root function $\sqrt{\vphantom{f}\dots}$, and also both $a$ and $b$ in the formula.
4. Part (5) is wrong. If $f$ was differentiable (presumably, in the sense of Fréchet, or some equivalent. Check the definition you were given in class, and also the relevant theorems) then we would have $D_vf(x) = \nabla f(x)\cdot v$, and part (3) shows this is wrong.

### Some graphs  ([interactive math3d.org graph link](https://www.math3d.org/2aNISLI7))

$$z=f(x,y)$$
[image]
[image]

---

$$z=\frac{df}{dx}(x,y)$$
[image]

---

$$z=\frac{df}{dy}(x,y)$$
[image]